# Confusion regarding usage of templated base class pointer pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism

This is a regular old polymorphism design scenario except that

```
template<typename Params> class Base {
   Base(Params& params):
     params_(params) {
     }
   virtual void run() = 0;
   Params params_;
};

class Derived1: public Base<Derived1Params> {
   Derived1(Derived1Params& params):
    Base(params) {
   }
   void run() {
   }
};
```

In the above situation, I cannot use the regular old, "use base_ptr to point to derived object" technique for run-time polymorphism, due to the templates, like below

```
Base* bp; // An error!!!
Derived1 dr;
bp = &dr;
```

What is the best pattern for this scenario?

Comment: Make `Base` inherit from a pure interface class.

Comment: @RichardCritten I so agree it is a good design principle in a lot of cases. And you set yourself up nicely for unit testing and dependency injection too.

Comment: Why is it necessary to store `params` in the base class (or anywhere for that matter)? You won't be able to access the data without knowing its type (at least not without UB) and anything else except for the constuctor is pure virtual. Why don't you pass by const ref btw? It seems like you're using the copy constructor for initializing `params`...

Comment: @RichardCritten You Sir! Are a genius. That is very useful. I will have a Base, and then a TemplatedBase class!